# Java Code for different timestamps for each row

Tags: java

Am using `getdate(),` But it's inserting same timestamps for all row in DB.

Ex :

```
id      logDatetime

1      Jan  5 2014  9:47PM

2      Jan  5 2014  9:47PM

3      Jan  5 2014  9:47PM
```

I want different timestamps for each row like below example,

Ex:

```
id       logDatetime

1     Jan  5 2014  9:47PM

2     Jan  5 2014  9:48PM

3     Jan  5 2014  9:49PM
```

is it possible? please suggest me.

Comment: can't suggest without seeing the code

Comment: Who said they both are same ?  see the complete time stamp. Not half.

Comment: You'll need different transactions, or they'll have the same transaction timestamp; transactions are atomic.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ, it's inserting same timestamps(9:47PM) for all row.

Comment: @sudheeranjs Check milliseconds too.

Comment: It differs in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and define your timestamp at a more granular level - like millis:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss.SSS aa");
System.out.println(sd.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
```

**Output:**

> 06 Jan 2014 01:05:02.894 PM